# Execute a IQueryable object?

Tags: asp.net

i am doing some research about entity data model in asp.net and there is one make me confused. 
e.g.

```
var tombstoneQuery = from t in crnnsupContext.Tombstones
                                                 from p in crnnsupContext.ProvStates
                                                  where t.RegNumber == _username && t.Province_State == p.ProvinceStateID
                                                  select t;
```

what i want to do is push all the retrieved result into the cache when user login, so it just connect database once.

so i insert tombtoneQuery into Cache. the problem is how i can get the data from the tombstoneQuery, as I know it is a IQueryable object right? so is there a way to execute it?

I have saw someone done this

```
ObjectResult<Contact> results = (from c in context.Contacts
                             select c).Execute();
```

but it poped up an error said IQueryable does not contain a definition for Execute() 
anyone can help. much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *execute* the query and materialize the results, it sounds like you really want:

```
List<TombStone> results = tombstoneQuery.ToList();
```

... and then put that in your cache.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `.ToList()`, which will return a `List<T>` with a local copy of all the results.